# Unit testing errors in Angular 14

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular14

I created a brand new Angular project using the cli `ng new ...`
and when I run `npm test` I get the below error in the browser:

[image]

and in the console I see this error:

[image]

I've not added anything extra;

I tested with Node versions 14.17.1 and 16.16.0 (I am on macOS, and using nvm); I tried uninstalling both Node versons, deleted all nvm cache files, installed Node again, but still getting the error

How can I debug or solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much trial and error found out its due to chrome out of date; once I updated chrome to the latest version its started working.